# Is BLEXBot crawler used by Google?

Tags: .htaccess, seo, bots, web-crawler

I have setup my htaccess this way

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*google.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*yahoo.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*ask.* search_robot

Order Deny,Allow
Deny from All
Allow from env=search_robot
```

I have this bot showing up:

```
IPv4 address:198.143.187.122
Reverse DNS:blexn3.webmeup.com
RIR:ARIN
Country:United States 
RBL Status:Clear
Thread:No threats detected
```

Is this bot used by Google or I am missing something?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No BLEXBot is not google. It belongs to a company called WebMeUp. You can find information [about them here](http://webmeup.com/about.html).

If you lookup the IP in the log you will see it's not Google.

```
IP Address      198.143.187.122
Host            blexn3.webmeup.com
Location        US   US, United States
City            Chicago, IL 60661
Organization    SingleHop
ISP             SingleHop
```

Google IPs will list Google as the organisation.

Google use their own Bots, they are custom built. You can [read up about them here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en), including a definitive list of their user-agent strings which may be useful to you.

To block follow the [instructions here](http://webmeup-crawler.com/).

Comment: Thanks, Scott. How this bot pass my htaccess restriction?

Comment: @user278963 I have added a link to instructions to block it. The best way to block a bot is using a file called `robots.txt` at the root of your website. All bots are supposed to follow these rules. It's easier and more efficient than managing rules through `.htaccess`

Comment: @user278963 It passed your restriction because it's user agent string contains `bot` i.e. `BLEXBot` which by your rule passes `SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent .*bot.* search_robot` = `Allow from env=search_robot`

Comment: I have to use htaccess file, 'coz I blocked all countries except one. If I make robots.txt and remove this code up "SetEnvIfNoCase" for bots. No way any bot can see anything, 'coz it is prohibited by htaccess file.

Comment: @user278963 Fair enough I can see why you need the .htaccess then.